# Document.write() is giving back "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null""

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript

I am using Angular2 for the front end on a website. It will be iframed into another website. when using the HTTP post method i receive the response which is json

[This is the API Post method. it will return a json result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDc9U.png)

in the front end sending of the post request i take the response and put it into json. then i set a variable in my AppService class with a set method. then in the completion of the HTTP request i open a new tab and fill it with the HTML. using the document.write() is where i get the error

[This is the front end Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTKff.png)

the 2 options i thought of to solve this were sending a window.postmessage() to the parent of the iFrame to try and open the new tab. Or make another iFrame inside of the current however both of these are non-optimal.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: Apparently the `window.open()` failed. Maybe because of a popup blocker.

Comment: As rightly suggested by @[Björn Tantau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2695799/bj%c3%b6rn-tantau), `window.open` inside a callback will be blocked by adBlockers. You should check if window is opened and if yes, then only do processing

Comment: i think you're correct! More answers appreciated

Comment: Please post your code as code and not as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely possible that a pop-up window gets blocked by the browser. If that happens, `window.open()` returns `null` and you need to write your script to handle this situation.

Most modern browsers are pretty "clever" about blocking pop-up windows, meaning they only allow a script to open one as a direct consequence of a user interaction. Because of this, running `window.open()` on the completion of an AJAX request is very likely to fail. One way to solve this is to open the window immediately when the user has initiated the action, then perform the AJAX request and write to the window when it's successful. Something like this:

```
button.onClick = function() {
  var popUp = window.open();
  if (popUp) {
    doAjaxRequest().then(function(data) {
      popUp.document.write(data);
      popUp.document.close();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Opening window on button click is not what OP is looking for. He is opening in `error` block of AJAX. Also, this has been covered in comments section.

Comment: @Rajesh OP's code indicates that the action results from a login attempt, that's most certainly something that follows a user interaction. The button click was just my example to illustrate the principle. The fact that pop-up windows are likely to only be allowed as a direct result of user interaction and disallowed otherwise hasn't even been mentioned in the comments. My answer provides useful information about what the issue is and what OP can do, if anything, to resolve it. The comments basically only re-states the fact that `window.open()` failed.